# Sorting a List of strings by 2 decimal points

Tags: c#, string, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list by a value in one of the x objects the list holds. Here is the order i need:

```
1
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
1.5
1.10
1.11
1.12
4.1
4.2
4.15
```

I've tried the following:

```
var lRetItems = lExportItems.OrderBy(d => d.linkid*);
```

and

```
IEnumerable<item> lRetItems = 
from x in lExportItems
orderby x.linkid*
select x;
```

*linkid = string

but neither give me the order i want as with these approaches 1.10 follows 1.1 instead of 1.2 following 1.1. Here's an example of the incorrect ordering the above approaches provide:

```
1
1.1
1.10
1.11
1.12
1.2
1.3
1.4
...
```

Does anyone have any idea how i might order the list in the same way as the first example?

If this were a double than 1.10 would be the same as 1.1...hence the ordering above. But i would of expected a string to at least sort by length?

Does anyone know of an approach that could provide the orider i require from these strings?

Here's a Rextester showing what I've tried based off comments (this fails):

http://rextester.com/JJB33165

Thanks.

Comment: That code in rextester has two issues. `"1,", "2"` must be replaced with `"1.0", "2.0"` or similar. The minor version is mandatory. Once you fix that, it sorts the versions properly.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't avoid having 1 alongside 1.1, it needs to be like this, so it seems that particular solution will not work.

Comment: And I guess you can't use 1.0 instead of 1, right? Can the number before the point have more than 1 digit? You can create a new class which receives the string and internally stores it as two integers, and also implement `IComparable`. That may be a good approach (similar to the ones in the other previous linked question).

Comment: Dan, could you solve this?

Answer (score 5):

```
var result = lRetItems.OrderBy(x => Version.Parse(x));
```

You can use [**Version**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Here live demo in [**Rextester**](http://rextester.com/RZFVXY33092)

Comment: `lRetItems.OrderBy(x => new Version(x));` also working.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Yes this is another possibility.

Comment: So i'Ve tried this but it gives me a crazy ordering! 8.9 - 8.7 - 8.2 - 9. This on a collection of strings that are concurrently filled from 1...1.10 - 2...2.10... and so on.

Comment: Tried this on rexter and you'll see a failure with the following string array:

            IEnumerable<string> test = new List<string>() { "1,", "2", "1.10", "1.1", "1.2", "2.1", "2.10" };

Do you know of any way around that with the method you've provided?

Comment: http://rextester.com/JJB33165

Comment: You just need to read what the error says. Like I commented in your question, that code in rextester has two issues. `"1,", "2"` must be replaced with `"1.0", "2.0"` or similar. The minor version is mandatory. Once you fix that, it sorts the versions properly.

Comment: great solution, worked well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a comparer function that will take two values, split them by the point (.) and compare integer before comparing fractional part converted to an int.

This however will be inefficient as a lot of time will be spent parsing strings to ints - multiple times per item, however as a start it will get you what you need.

```
    public static int Compare(string a, string b)
    {
        // Locate point (if exists)
        var pointA = a.IndexOf('.'); 
        if(pointA == -1)
            pointA = a.Length;
        var pointB = a.IndexOf('.'); 
        if(pointB == -1)
            pointB = a.Length;
        // Get integers
        var intA = int.Parse(a.Substring(0, pointA));
        var intB = int.Parse(b.Substring(0, pointA));
        if(intA == intB)
        {
            // Get fractionals
            intA = int.Parse(a.Substring(pointA+1));
            intB = int.Parse(b.Substring(pointB+1));
        }
        return intB-intA;
    }
```

Comment: I submit to @mybirthname's solution using the `Version` class.  Code reuse and all that.  The most optimal version however would be to convert (parse) all strings into the `Version` class first, and then do the sort.

Comment: Unfortunately it fails:

http://rextester.com/JJB33165

Comment: @DanHall, "it fails" being the `Version.Parse(x)` example on the "other" answer rather than my example here?